# android color picker "cannot be resolved to a type"

Tags: android, color-picker

maybe this is a very simple question...but i am a rather new beginner...please tolerate me.

I am now developing a drawing app and would like to allow user to choose color through a color picker.

I have seen the AmbilWarna dialog and has copied the following to my app:

### Code:

```
package com.pearappx.drawing;
import com.pearmak.drawing.ui.dialog.AmbilWarnaDialog.OnAmbilWarnaListener;

// other codes and declarations

   public OnClickListener setColorPickerDialogListener = new OnClickListener() 
   {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) 
      {   
          AmbilWarnaDialog dialog = new AmbilWarnaDialog(Doodlz.this, currtentColor, new OnAmbilWarnaListener()     
          {          
              @Override
               public void onCancel(AmbilWarnaDialog dialog) {     ;}
               @Override
               public void onOk(AmbilWarnaDialog dialog, int color) 
               {
                   colorRedBtn.setbackgroundcolor(color);
               }

          });
          dialog.show();
      };
   };
```

### Question:

There are many red underlines in the OnCLickListener block for quoting "AmbilWarnaDialog cannot be resolved to a type" . This maybe because the AmbilWarnaDialog not properly imported??

This is because there is also an error shown at the import part. I am importing by writing as:
`import com.pearmak.drawing.ui.dialog.AmbilWarnaDialog.OnAmbilWarnaListener`; but it also underlines this phrase as the above error too.

I have followed http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html already and has clicked "apply" before closing the reference dialog.

How could this be solved?
Many thanks!!!

Comment: is `OnAmbilWarnaListener` in a library (*.jar)? i notice that it's package is very different from your class' package. if so, did you include the jar file in the build path? you should be able to create all imports by typing `Cntl-Shift-O`.

Comment: yes i have included the 2 jar file in the build path already but still fails

Comment: `Cntl-Shift-O` (upper case letter 'o') should be able to find them (it does for me!). have you refreshed your project?

Comment: is it necessary to add in the Libraries of the app properties, and click add JARs for the 2 java: AmbilWarnaDialog.java and AmbilWarnaKotak.java and then tick them in Order and Export tab?

Comment: i'm not sure what you mean. You should have created an Android Library project at some point, coded what you wanted and built it. in the `/bin` directory there will be a *.jar file. if you put that *.jar file in your application (in the `/libs` directory?) and then add it to the build path, you should be golden. Is that what you mean?

Comment: I still fails...could you kindly provide me steps for adding it? Many thanks in advance...

Comment: it's supposed to be in a library (*.jar) file, right? or am i way off?

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidLibraryProjects/article.html is where i went when i created my library project. (again, assuming that's what you're after)

Comment: thanks a lot for the detailed guide!! let me try

Comment: it finally works!!! thanks a lot!!!! could you please post it as an answer so that i accept it? =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is library project to place your Dialog into. Once you have that working, copy the `*.jar` file out of the `\bin` directory and import it into your main app. Be sure to modify your app's Build Path such that it includes the new `*.jar` file.

for a great introduction to library projects, check out: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidLibraryProjects/article.html. It's where i started and it worked like a champ for me.

good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot!! and sorry for my beginner's inadequate skills :)